# Why does Visual Studio's web service serialization engine change when I make reference to an abstract class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, compiler-construction

I noticed this yesterday after some sleuthing, but wasn't happy with just knowing about it. Could someone explain this to me?

Here's what I'm experiencing:

- I see two different serialization possibilities:

  - `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]`
  - `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]`
- Serialization involving Runtime.Serialization causes the entity `ArrayOf<T>` to be introduced if any collections are expected as parameters to web methods.

  - public void Foo(int[] ids) ==> public void Foo(int[] ids) **System.ServiceModel**
  - public void Foo(int[] ids) ==> public void Foo(ArrayOfInt ids) **System.Runtime.Serialization**
- The serialization engine chosen is dependent on a paramater deriving from (or being) an abstract class type.

  - public void Bar(int[] ids) ==> **System.Runtime.Serialization** is used.
  - public void Bar(DerivedFromAbstractClass baz, int[] ids) ==> **System.ServiceModel** is used.

As a runnable example:

```
public abstract class Foo { }

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = System.Web.Services.WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public void HelloWorld(Foo foo, int[] ids)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is what my .asmx file looks like. Note the paramater types expected by hello world. Now, I generate a service reference:

```
namespace CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference1 {
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.WebService1Soap")]
    public interface WebService1Soap {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld", ReplyAction="*")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
        void HelloWorld(CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference1.Foo foo, int[] ids);
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
    public abstract partial class Foo : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface WebService1SoapChannel : CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference1.WebService1Soap, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class WebService1SoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference1.WebService1Soap>, CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference1.WebService1Soap {

        public WebService1SoapClient() {
        }

        public WebService1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public WebService1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public WebService1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public WebService1SoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public void HelloWorld(CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference1.Foo foo, int[] ids) {
            base.Channel.HelloWorld(foo, ids);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the absence of ArrayOfInt. Now, I remove the Foo paramater from WebService1 and generate a second service reference. Observe:

```
namespace CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2 {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="ArrayOfInt", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", ItemName="int")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class ArrayOfInt : System.Collections.Generic.List<int> {
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference2.WebService1Soap")]
    public interface WebService1Soap {

        // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since element name ids from namespace http://tempuri.org/ is not marked nillable
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld", ReplyAction="*")]
        CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldResponse HelloWorld(CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldRequest request);
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class HelloWorldRequest {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="HelloWorld", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
        public CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldRequestBody Body;

        public HelloWorldRequest() {
        }

        public HelloWorldRequest(CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldRequestBody Body) {
            this.Body = Body;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
    public partial class HelloWorldRequestBody {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=0)]
        public CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.ArrayOfInt ids;

        public HelloWorldRequestBody() {
        }

        public HelloWorldRequestBody(CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.ArrayOfInt ids) {
            this.ids = ids;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class HelloWorldResponse {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="HelloWorldResponse", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
        public CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldResponseBody Body;

        public HelloWorldResponse() {
        }

        public HelloWorldResponse(CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldResponseBody Body) {
            this.Body = Body;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
    public partial class HelloWorldResponseBody {

        public HelloWorldResponseBody() {
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public interface WebService1SoapChannel : CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.WebService1Soap, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class WebService1SoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.WebService1Soap>, CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.WebService1Soap {

        public WebService1SoapClient() {
        }

        public WebService1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public WebService1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public WebService1SoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public WebService1SoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldResponse CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.WebService1Soap.HelloWorld(CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.HelloWorld(request);
        }

        public void HelloWorld(CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.ArrayOfInt ids) {
            CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldRequest inValue = new CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldRequest();
            inValue.Body = new CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldRequestBody();
            inValue.Body.ids = ids;
            CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.HelloWorldResponse retVal = ((CableSolve.Web.Api.Tests.ServiceReference2.WebService1Soap)(this)).HelloWorld(inValue);
        }
    }
}
```

What the heck? **Why does HelloWorld's second paramater's type expectations depend on the existence of another paramater deriving from or being an abstract class? Is it possible to have HelloWorld only expect int[] ids without the Foo paramater, but not have it expect ArrayOfInt?**